# How can I halt my new PC instead of poweroff when I call 'shutdown -H now'?

Tags: debian, halt

I want to have the message `system halted` after command `shutdown -H now`, but my new PC after this command power-off the machine.

With my old PC that command worked fine. But my new PC is powered down after the command `shutdown -H now` instead of halting with message `system halted` on screen. What happened?

How to return normal behaviour of the `shutdown -H now` command?

OS version is Debian 8.5. Same version of OS is using on both machines, but reactions on `shutdown -H now` command are different.

Could it be settings in BIOS?
Could it be a hardware problem?

Comment: That should work. What happened?

Comment: Which operating system version are you using? Since the "poweroff" operation is usually used more often than just "halt", some Linux distributions may default to assuming the user means "poweroff" when  "halt" is used, but there is likely a configuration file that can be used to fix it. The details will depend on the used distribution & version.

Comment: I moved your comments to your question (you can also edit you question).

Comment: Of course, but tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 9.x and, if I recall correctly, also in 8.x, the default behavior of `shutdown -h now` is determined by file `/etc/default/halt`.

By default, it says:

```
# Default behaviour of shutdown -h / halt. Set to "halt" or "poweroff".
HALT=poweroff
```

Change the second line to `HALT=halt`, and then you should have your halt without an automatic power-down.

Older versions of the `shutdown` command did not care about the case of the `-H` option, for compatibility with other Unix-style systems; Debian 9 seems to have `shutdown -H` always halt, `shutdown -P` always power-down, and `shutdown -h` will do whatever the configuration file says. I don't have a Debian 8 system at hand, but it might be that Debian 8 is old enough to have a version of `shutdown` that still treats `-H` as equivalent to `-h`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but you don't read my ask properly. "**Same** version of OS is using on both machines, but reactions on `shutdown -H now` command are different." On my old PC command works correctly.

Comment: Does your old PC have the `/etc/default/halt` file configured differently?

Comment: No no. Both systems configured absolutely equally straight from box.

Comment: Then the old PC might be incapable of powering down by software control, causing fallback to classic "halt" even with no modifications to `/etc/default/halt` configuration file. Maybe it has all its power management features disabled in BIOS, which might disable software power control too. On the new PC, you seem to be getting the default halt behavior of old Debian: "power down if possible, unless specifically configured not to."